# How to access data of the opened tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-devtools, webbrowser-control

I have mentioned the code below which I have been trying. I am successfully able to open a url in a new tab but unable to access the content using DOM. so someone please suggest me any ideas how to access the data...

Thank you in advance.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

        var url = "www.website.com";
        var Tab = window.open(url);
        var Name = Tab.document.getElementsByClassName('uniquename').innerHTML;
        alert(Name);

        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI, getElementsByClassName returns an array, not a single element.

Comment: The classname is unique and it has single string that is the name... So I get the name... This is working fine in console window of chrome but not working through the embeded javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onLoad event in this case as:

```
var url = "www.website.com";
    var Tab = window.open(url);

Tab.onload = function () {
 var elems = Tab.document.getElementsByClassName('uniquename');
 elems.forEach(function(elem,index){
  console.log(elem)
 })
};
```

But your URL in the child window should be in same domain.

Comment: I am scripting the java code in the local html file and running it while the URL is of a website.

Comment: @Karan -- please note that "Java" and "Javascript" are two different things, and are not interchangeable.  I believe you are talking about "Javascript" in this case, not "Java".

Comment: Oh sorry yeah I meant Javascript only :D